How to get a unique and immutable device identifier in Flutter for Android?
I am building a Flutter app where I need to identify devices uniquely. Ideally, the identifier should:

Be unique to each Android device.
Remain constant even after app updates or reinstallation.
Not change after a factory reset, if possible.

I have explored the following options:

Android ID: Can reset after a factory reset or if a new user profile is created.
IMEI: Deprecated on newer Android versions (API 29+), and accessing it requires special permissions.
UUID with Secure Storage: Works well for app-specific needs but is not a true device-wide identifier.

Is there a reliable method in Flutter to get a unique device identifier that fits these criteria? If not, what is the best alternative to achieve this in a privacy-compliant way?
Code examples or package recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

If anyone know about it please help because i am trying to get almost 10 days.

I would think it's pretty much impossible
